# Set y-axis as count of hue using pandas + seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   unique_id  element   day-only
0   52221039    4       28
1   5212263     3       28
2   5244438     LS      27
3   4975676     4       22
4   9023691     1       24
```

I'm trying to get a `lmplot` that maps out the frequency at which `element` appears every day, the same as the following countplot, basically.

`fig = sns.countplot(x="day-only", hue="element", data=df, hue_order=["1","2","3","4","LS","EA"], palette=color_element)`

However, I can't seem to find a way to map my count of `element` to the y value. I've tried

```
horse = df["element"].value_counts()
count_of_y = numpy.asarray(horse)
```

And then `fig = sns.lmplot(x="day-only", y=count_of_y, hue="element", data=df)`

That hasn't worked, of course, with seaborn documentation telling me that y has to be equal to a column in my dataframe. And I can't seem to find a way to get a simple count of element as my measure on y axis. I've also tried counting my `unique_id`, but that hasn't worked either.

This feels like a really simple question, and yet I can't seem to find a solution! Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is 'Mark' in `fig = sns.lmplot(x="day-only", y=count_of_y, hue="Mark", data=df)`?

Comment: Should have been hue="element", apologies for the confusion, edited to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized where my error lay and solved my problem. I created a new dataframe in the following way:

```
count_of_y = df["element"].groupby(df["day-only"]).value_counts().rename("counts").reset_index()
count_of_y
```

Which gave me three columns, with counts in the right place. I was then able to plot with this.

`fig = sns.lmplot(x="day-only", y="counts", hue="element", data=count_of_y, hue_order=["1","2","3","4","LS", "EA"], palette=color_element)`